# unable to connect to database in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am reading [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/01/mysql-nodejs-intro/) and tried to connect to MYSQL database using node js.Here is my program

```
var mysql =  require('mysql');
var connection =  mysql.createConnection({
host : "localhost",
    User : "root",
password: ""
 });
connection.connect();
connection.query("use test");
var strQuery = "select * from chat";    

connection.query( strQuery, function(err, rows){
if(err) {
    throw err;
}else{
    console.log( rows );
}
 })
  connection.destroy( );
```

I an not getting any error but also unable to get any output

Comment: @Quentin I have changed quotes but I am not getting any error but also not getting output as well

Comment: I voted too fast to close, there is another blocking problem.

Comment: @dystroy what should I do now?

Comment: Does it work with `end()` ?

Comment: @dystroy yeah it worked with `connection.end()` but why `destroy()` was not working any idea?

Comment: @dystroy but it is giving output as `[ { chat_name: 'John' } ]`.Could you tell me how to get just john from here.

Comment: Use `rows[0].chat_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the program wait for your queries to be executed, replace

```
connection.destroy();
```

with

```
connection.end();
```

Comment: I have used standard quotes but now I am not getting output

Comment: Well. Change your standard and use the same quotes as other developers.

Comment: I am not getting any error but also not getting output as well

Comment: but it is giving output as `[ { chat_name: 'John' } ]`.Could you tell me how to get just john from here

Comment: @Fresher try console.log( rows[0].chat_name );